# My new route is not working in magento

Tags: magento2

I have created new controller, module and route file. route not working, its showing 404 error.

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace Inchoo\userlogin\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()
    {

      try { 
          $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
          $error = 'false';

          //Get input values.
          $email = $params['email'];
          $password = sha1(sha1($params['password']));

          //Check if values are not empty
          if( !$email ){
            $error = 'true';
            $response['msg'] = "Email is required";
          }
          if( !$password ){
            $error = 'true';
            $response['msg'] = "Password is required";
          }

          //Connect with database with connetion file.
          $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
          ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
          $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
          if ( $error == 'false') {
            //Check if email and password matched.
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `customer_entity` where email="' . $email .'" and password="' . $password .'"';
            $login = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
          }
          //Check if login is successfull or unsuccessfull.
          if ( isset($login) && $error == 'false')
          {
            $response["status"] = 'true';
            $response["data"] = array();
            $response["data"] = $login;
            echo json_encode($response);
          } else {
            $response["data"] = [];
            $response["status"] =  'false';
            $response['msg'] = $response['msg'];
            echo json_encode($response);
          }
        } 
        catch (Exception $e){ 
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }

    }
}
```

**Module:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="login" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Route:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="login" frontName="login">
            <module name="login" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Unfortunately problem is still same. any other idea please.

Answer (score 3):

Change module name in `module.xml` also in `routes.xml`

```
login
```

replace to:

```
Inchoo_Userlogin
```

change class name in controller file:

```
Inchoo\userlogin\Controller\Index;
```

replace to:

```
Inchoo\Userlogin\Controller\Index;
```

Please add `registration.php` at     `Inchoo\Userlogin\registration.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Inchoo_Userlogin',
    __DIR__
);
```

Run command:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After that run command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Unfortunately problem is still same. any other idea please.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

First error in **app\code\Inchoo\Userlogin\etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Inchoo_Userlogin" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

second error in  **app\code\Inchoo\Userlogin\etc\frontend\routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="login" frontName="login">
            <module name="Inchoo_Userlogin" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

and in controller `userlogin` will be `Userlogin`

```
 <?php

namespace Inchoo\Userlogin\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()
    {

      try { 
          $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
          $error = 'false';

          //Get input values.
          $email = $params['email'];
          $password = sha1(sha1($params['password']));

          //Check if values are not empty
          if( !$email ){
            $error = 'true';
            $response['msg'] = "Email is required";
          }
          if( !$password ){
            $error = 'true';
            $response['msg'] = "Password is required";
          }

          //Connect with database with connetion file.
          $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
          ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
          $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
          if ( $error == 'false') {
            //Check if email and password matched.
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `customer_entity` where email="' . $email .'" and password="' . $password .'"';
            $login = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
          }
          //Check if login is successfull or unsuccessfull.
          if ( isset($login) && $error == 'false')
          {
            $response["status"] = 'true';
            $response["data"] = array();
            $response["data"] = $login;
            echo json_encode($response);
          } else {
            $response["data"] = [];
            $response["status"] =  'false';
            $response['msg'] = $response['msg'];
            echo json_encode($response);
          }
        } 
        catch (Exception $e){ 
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Unfortunately problem is still same. any other idea please.

Comment: running this command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` showing your module name listed